# Is there autosave for RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

I've had instances where RStudio gets aborted and I lose my progress.

Is there autosave, at least for the R Scripts?

I think there might be something comparable on Windows. I am using RStudio on Mac.

Comment: No autosave that I know of.

Comment: Any extensions or anything towards that end?

Comment: Oh, I was assuming for the R environment (`.Rdata`), not just for script files. @zan_li's answer points to something more informative.

Comment: Would be great for the R environment too.

Comment: Cauder, I understand what you're talking about ... and think that Konrad's answer is very appropriate here: you might see some use, but there are several ways that it would be a problem, and not just from a viewpoint of performance/responsiveness (which would take a significant hit).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Autosave for scripts exists**. To enable autosave, go to “Preferences” › “Code” › “Saving” › “Auto-save”.

[image: preferences screenshot]

Regardless of the existence of autosave you should get in the habit of saving your script all the time. Case in point, when programming it’s not uncommon for me to save the current file several times *per line typed*. This takes up *no time at all*, thanks to shortcuts. It happens completely automatically.

---

**Autosave for session data would kill [reproducibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducibility#Reproducible_data).** It would be the ultimate anti-feature. Therefore not only does this feature not exist (per se), *it’s actively undesirable.*

To avoid losing your progress, write a script instead of executing code directly in the R shell. To save the results of expensive computations, decompose your logic into small blocks, and cache intermediate results.

[RMarkdown allows you to do this out of the box](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/r-code.html); for other scripts, you can approximate the same using `readRDS` and `loadRDS`, or using a proper [reproducibility framework such as Makefiles](http://stat545.com/automation04_make-activity.html), or [drake](https://github.com/ropensci/drake).

Comment: You mention Autosave for scripts exists. How do I access it?

Comment: @Cauder It’s automatically on. If you reopen RStudio after a crash, it recovers previously opened, unsaved files. However, RStudio itself should never crash (personally I can’t remember that ever happening).

Comment: Where do the autosaves get saved on MacOS? I'm experiencing functionality different from what you're describing.

Comment: @Cauder Are you saying that your RStudio crashes? As in, the IDE itself, not just the R session? If so, that’s extremely concerning; I’d suggest reinstalling. At any rate, if no data is restored in this case then chances are no data got saved (again, this would be very concerning). Unfortunately I don’t know *where* this data is supposed to be saved but your best course of action in this case would be to report a bug to RStudio directly.

Comment: Hey Konrad. My RStudio regularly crashes. I get a "cannot connect to session" message and then an "R Aborted" message. It happened just today and I lost all the models that I ran overnight.

Comment: Interestingly, it just happened again. "R session aborted. R encountered a fatal error. The session was terminated." I wasn't doing anything crazy, just a ggplot with a couple loess curves.

Comment: And when it reloads, I have an empty environment and my scripts are gone (except, of course, the saves I have from the last time I manually saved)

Comment: @Cauder That’s crazy, sorry you’re having these problems. All I can recommend is, try to uninstall and completely reinstall R, RStudio and all your packages. It’s possible that there’s a version mismatch between one of the packages you’re loading and R; but the fact that this also crashes/reloads RStudio is not normal.

Comment: It looks this feature got removed in recent versions of RStudio. There are options to save on idle.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is.

> 1) Autosaves are stored in %LOCALAPPDATA%\RStudio-Desktop.
>
> 2) [they are generated] Almost instantaneously (about every half second)

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/208611187-Missing-Autosave

Comment: I know that's true on Windows. Is that true on MacOS?