How to autosave R files
I'm using RStudio more and more, and most often I create files such as .R, .Rmd and .html.
I want to have the versions/make it possible to have version control. Therefore, I uploaded the files to OneDrive but of course the files are only saved when I remember to save using CTRL+S.
Is there a way to set the R document to autosave every 5th minute, or something similar?

? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55598269/is-there-autosave-for-rstudio

Side note: Onedrive is not the best cloud service one can use, and certainly inappropriate for sensible data. You might want to write your session info to a file or work with a version securing/controlling environment.

While there is no substitute for getting into the habit of regularly doing CTRL+S every time you make a change, you can achieve your desired outcome using the later package and a custom function.
The auto_save function below will run until you close your R session, and it:

checks to make sure the OneDrive path and files you list/want to save exist. It will stop() if not, and prints a message telling you the cause of the error
prints a message in the console letting you know when each file was saved.

To check the function is working as expected (without having to wait five minutes), I recommend changing the later(auto_save, delay = 300) to something like later(auto_save, delay = 10). Then, once you are sure it works:

close R and restart
edit back to later(auto_save, delay = 300)
run the auto_save function code again
then run later(auto_save, delay = 0)

install.packages("later")
library(later)

library(later)

auto_save <- function() {
  
  # Files in your working directory you want to save (add more where necessary)
  files <- c("your_script.R", "your_rmd.Rmd")
  
  # OneDrive path for saving files
  onedrive_path <- "C:/path/to/your/onedrive"
  
  # Check if the OneDrive path and the files exist, stop if not
  if (!dir.exists(onedrive_path)) {
    
    stop(cat("OneDrive path does not exist:", onedrive_path, "\n"))
    
  }
  
  missing_files <- files[!file.exists(files)]
  
  if (length(missing_files) > 0) {
    
    stop(cat("The following files are missing:\n", paste(missing_files, collapse = ", "), "\n"))
    
  }
  
  # Define the destination file paths
  backup_files <- file.path(onedrive_path, files)
  
  # Copy files and print status to console
  lapply(seq_along(files), function(i) {
    
    file.copy(files[i], backup_files[i], overwrite = TRUE)
    cat("Saved:", files[i], "\n   to:", backup_files[i], "\n   at:",
        format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), "\n")
    
  })
  
  # Schedule function to run again after n seconds
  later(auto_save, delay = 300)
  
}

To run the auto_save function:
later(auto_save, delay = 0)

